# How to remove logo image?

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to remove a logo image from the bottom of my page. The logo is generated by the following function:

```
function addLogoContentBlock($content, $styles) {
if(empty($content['blocks'])) return $content;
$content['blocks'][] = array(
  'type' => 'container',
  'orientation' => 'horizontal',
  'styles' => array(
    'block' => array(
      'backgroundColor' => (!empty($styles['body']['backgroundColor'])) ?
        $styles['body']['backgroundColor'] :
        'transparent'
    )
  ),
  'blocks' => array(
    array(
      'type' => 'container',
      'orientation' => 'vertical',
      'styles' => array(
      ),
      'blocks' => array(
        array(
          'type' => 'image',
          'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
          'src' => Env::$assets_url . '/img/logo.png',
          'fullWidth' => false,
          'alt' => 'logo',
          'width' => '108px',
          'height' => '65px',
          'styles' => array(
            'block' => array(
              'textAlign' => 'center'
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
return $content;
}
```

How can I remove the logo? I tried setting `$content['blocks']` to null but that didn't work.

Comment: comment return $content?

Comment: Maybe `if(empty($content['blocks'])) return '';`. This will made that function will return empty string if $content['blocks'] is empty.

Comment: Also, why do you want to remove logo from function that makes logo? Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: abuse the CSS criteria: `'styles' => array(
            'block' => array(
              'textAlign' => 'center',
'display' => 'none'
            )
          )`

Answer (score 0):

You could remove this line

```
          'src' => Env::$assets_url . '/img/logo.png',
```

from your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to hide this image

```
img[alt='logo']{
display: none;
}
```

you can capture it by **alt** attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
 array(
          'type' => 'image',
          'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
          'src' => Env::$assets_url . '/img/logo.png',
          'fullWidth' => false,
          'alt' => 'logo',
          'width' => '108px',
          'height' => '65px',
          'styles' => array(
            'block' => array(
              'textAlign' => 'center',
              'display' => 'none'           // add this string
            )
          )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but `display: none` is not showing up in the inline style attributes for the image element.